# How to block cookies in Chrome at admin level?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I would like to know, how to block cookies at admin level, in `Google Chrome` at Administrator level, (therefore, making them impossible to delete) as the SpywareBlaster sets them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use gpo rules you can download on Google website, the rules allows to enforce various settings.

The tool you are talking about probably studied the registry changes made by the gootorules and applied them raw.